# Hibernate @ManyToOne with join table with extra column seems generate infinite loop

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have 3 entities : Contract, Person and ContractPerson. ContractPerson is a join table between Contract and Person with extra fields so I created a separate entity.

Contract.java:

```
   import lombok.Data;
   import javax.persistence.*;
   import java.util.HashSet;
   import java.util.Set;

   @Data
   @Entity
   @Table (name = "contract")
   public class Contract {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue
       @Column (name = "contract_id")
       private Long id;

       @Column (name = "contract_ref")
       private String ref;

       @OneToMany (mappedBy = "contract", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       private Set<ContractPerson> contractPersons = new HashSet<>();
    }
```

Person.java:

```
   import lombok.Data;
   import javax.persistence.*;

   @Data
   @Entity
   @Table (name = "person")
   public class Person {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue
       @Column (name = "person_id")
       private Long id;

       @Column (name = "formality")
       private String formality;

       @Column (name = "first_name")
       private String firstName;

       @Column (name = "last_name")
       private String lastName;

       @OneToMany (mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       private Set<ContractPerson> contractPersons = new HashSet<>();
    }
```

ContractPerson.java:

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@Table (name = "contract_person")
public class ContractPerson {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column (name = "contract_person_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column (name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "id_of_person")
    private Person person;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "id_of_contract")
    private Contract contract;
}
```

When I try with Spring Data JPA to get a contract with a particular id it generates this kind of input:

```
2014-12-29 18:02:10.843 DEBUG 1932 --- [qtp745716999-20] e.p.i.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl : Found row of collection: [xxx.Contract.contractPersons#199]
2014-12-29 18:02:10.843 DEBUG 1932 --- [qtp745716999-20] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : 1 collections were found in result set for role: xxx.Contract.contractPersons
2014-12-29 18:02:10.843 DEBUG 1932 --- [qtp745716999-20] stractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer : Loading collection: [xxx.Contract.contractPersons#199]
2014-12-29 18:02:10.879 DEBUG 1932 --- [qtp745716999-20] o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Preparing collection intializer : [xxx.Contract.contractPersons#199]
2014-12-29 18:02:10.879 DEBUG 1932 --- [qtp745716999-20] o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Starting ResultSet row #0
2014-12-29 18:02:10.879 DEBUG 1932 --- [qtp745716999-20] e.p.i.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl : Found row of collection: [xxx.Contract.contractPersons#199]
2014-12-29 18:02:10.880 DEBUG 1932 --- [qtp745716999-20] o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Starting ResultSet row #1
2014-12-29 18:02:10.880 DEBUG 1932 --- [qtp745716999-20] e.p.i.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl : Found row of collection: [xxx.Contract.contractPersons#199]
2014-12-29 18:02:10.880 DEBUG 1932 --- [qtp745716999-20] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : 1 collections were found in result set for role: xxx.Contract.contractPersons
etc...
```

After an impressive amount of repetition of this log I have this:

```
2014-12-29 18:25:41.805  WARN 1992 --- [tp2080715589-19] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@53504a5c<rs=com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@448cef4b>
2014-12-29 18:25:41.805  WARN 1992 --- [tp2080715589-19] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@3c4208bf<rs=com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@55932a51>
2014-12-29 18:25:41.805  WARN 1992 --- [tp2080715589-19] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@134c5281<rs=com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@44927753>
2014-12-29 18:25:41.805  WARN 1992 --- [tp2080715589-19] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@77bc9d0c<rs=com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@6520ed53>
2014-12-29 18:25:41.805  WARN 1992 --- [tp2080715589-19] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@7feabc3d<rs=com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@6a97c953>
2014-12-29 18:25:41.805  WARN 1992 --- [tp2080715589-19] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@bec8a67<rs=com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@4e0d0b57>
2014-12-29 18:25:41.805  WARN 1992 --- [tp2080715589-19] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@5672764e<rs=com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@1d0c0d57>
2014-12-29 18:25:41.806  WARN 1992 --- [tp2080715589-19] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@74b52738<rs=com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@5ee5b357>
```

If I remove the link in Contract there is no error.

Do you have any idea ? Infinite loop ? Other ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It seems this is caused by Lombok, [here](http://www.skybert.net/java/lombok/) is a possible solution to this problem (I haven't tested it personally though).

Comment: I removed Lombok and yes it solves my problem.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in `@ToString` since you have `@OneToMany` relationship between the `Person` and the `Contract`, it goes through an infinite loop and if you debug it, you will probably see `StackOverflowException` was thrown behind the scenes. Since `@Data` is a convenient shortcut annotation that bundles the features of `@ToString`, `@EqualsAndHashCode`, `@Getter` / `@Setter`, and `@RequiredArgsConstructor` together. So the best way is using these annotations separately and ignoring `@ToString` instead of using `@Data` as the following:

Contract.java:

```
import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table (name = "contract")
public class Contract {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column (name = "contract_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column (name = "contract_ref")
    private String ref;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "contract", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ContractPerson> contractPersons = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Person.java:

```
import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.*;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table (name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column (name = "person_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column (name = "formality")
    private String formality;

    @Column (name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column (name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<ContractPerson> contractPersons = new HashSet<>();
}
```

ContractPerson.java:

```
import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.*;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table (name = "contract_person")
public class ContractPerson {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column (name = "contract_person_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column (name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "id_of_person")
    private Person person;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "id_of_contract")
    private Contract contract;
}
```